# How to make a text animated in android?

Tags: android

In my android application I am trying to show a "Loading..." text which will change every 100 ms. After every 100 milliseconds it will increase one dot. So first it will be like "Loading." and the after another 100 ms it will be "Loading.." When it will be "Loading..." , this process will terminate and again start from the first on words. It will continue till 3500 ms. It will be pretty like progress bar.

I hope I am able to explain the problem.

How to resolve this problem? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the best answer, but it works.

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    for (int i = 100; i <= 3500; i=i+100) {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(i%300 == 0){
                    textView.setText("Loading.");
                }else if(i%200 == 0){
                    textView.setText("Loading..");
                }else if(i%100 == 0){
                    textView.setText("Loading...");
                }
            }
        }, i);
    }
```

Comment: This is an endless loop (`i=1+100`) :)

Comment: Oops! Sorry. Typo. I meant i = i+100; Changed.

Comment: Hmmm good. But I believe that approach as suggested by @BinyaminSharet is a good one if it works for you. But anyways, you have it working already.

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin Snippet for Animating (Loading...):

```
ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 4).apply {
        repeatCount = 10
        duration = 1000
        addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
                val dotsCount = valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue() as Int
                if (dotsCount < 4) {
                    spannable.setSpan(transparentColorSpan, 7 + dotsCount, 10,
                                  Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
                    textView.invalidate()
                }
      }
}.start()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, definitely the best option to go with.

Comment: Can you update the snippet with the full code?! I am really trying to make this work but without success, tried to make it work using this official Spans resources but also without success

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable

Answer (score 3):

A [`CountdownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) seems to fit, change the text in onTick.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an AsyncTask. This class is meant to do long-running background tasks that will publish updates and run on the UI thread automatically.

In `doInBackground`, have your loop that will then call `publishProgress` which will call `onProgressUpdate` every 100ms with the new values.

This will be done in the background and onProgressUpdate will run on the UI thread for you automatically.

Something on the lines of:

```
private class ShowLoading extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3500; i++){
            publishProgress(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        if (values[0]%3 == 0){
            textview.setText ("Loading.");
        } else if (values[0]%3 == 1){
            textview.setText ("Loading..");
        } else if (values[0]%3 == 2){
            textview.setText ("Loading..");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you're not serious. Handlers fits perfectly here, no need of creating threads etc...