# Trailing dot text animation

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make a trailing dot animation, as in "loading", then "loading.", then "loading..", the loading...", then "loading".

I really tried several ways using span but I am not succeding at it, I started my research using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53879584/11793333) and [the official doc on spans](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans).

My code is:

```
    val text = "Loading"
    val spannedText = SpannableStringBuilder("$text...")
    binding.textViewTitle.setText(spannedText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)

    val trailingDotsAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 4).apply {
        repeatCount = 10
        duration = 4000
        addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
            val dotsCount = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
            if (dotsCount < 4) {
                (binding.textViewTitle.text as SpannableString).setSpan(
                    ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
                    text.length + dotsCount,
                    text.length + 3,
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
                binding.textViewTitle.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }.start()
```

What I am getting right now is a textView without any dots whatsoever, and without further showing any extra dots.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need for invalidating the `TextView` or redrawing it again, I came up with a relatively similar solution which worked very well.

```kotlin
private fun setupTextView() {
        val text = "Loading "
        val spannedText = SpannableStringBuilder()

        ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 4).apply {
            repeatCount = 10
            duration = 4000
            addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
                val dotsCount = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
                spannedText.clear()
                repeat(dotsCount) { spannedText.append(".") }
                spannedText.setSpan(
                    ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
                    0,
                    spannedText.length,
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
                spannedText.insert(0, text)
                binding.textViewTitle.setText(spannedText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
            }
        }.start()
    }
```

Inserting the `Loading`  text after applying the span to the current dots' count will be better for the ease of calculating the length and the code's clarity.

Comment: thanks for the effort to help. I think it is a bug with Span/Invalidate. The idea behind invalidate is that you dont need to redraw (everything?) and the view will stay at the same size, only changing the foreground color of a certain range so it will be invisible thus enabling the "animation"